# Django rest-framework:How to let client know the pk so that it can get,update or delete

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

django rest framework

I have two api

```
url(r'^testall/$',views.DataList.as_view()),
url(r'^testone/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.DataDetail.as_view()),
```

I have a question ,the `r'^testone/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$` url can `get` ,`update`,and `delete`

But the user have to know the `pk`
How can I let client know the `pk` is    ??

views.py

```
class DataList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
class DataDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
```

This is my `models`

```
class Data(models.Model):

    mac_address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    ...
```

I have a field `mac_address`,which is unique and the client know that
I think maybe I can edit code to

```
 url(r'^testone/(?P<mac_address>\w+)/$',views.DataDetail.as_view())
```

But I got error:

```
Expected view DataDetail to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.
```

And I'm not sure use the `mac_address` with `:` in url  (`http://localhost:8000/test/A1:BC:34:WD:TT/`)  is a good idea
Please guide me
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here pk is lookup_field, 
when you call this url,`url(r'^testall/$',views.DataList.as_view())`
you will get response like

```
{'id': 4, 'mac_address': 3423, ..}
```

, here "id" is the "pk" This id can be used for calling

```
url(r'^testone/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.DataDetail.as_view()),
```

And
In views you can use mac_address as lookup_field,

```
url(r'^testone/(?P<mac_address>\w+)/$',views.DataDetail.as_view())

class DataDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    lookup_field = 'mac_address'
```

You can refer more http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview